# Split lines on spaces in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, transpose

How can i split lines in Sublime Text 3? I tried ctrl+t, ctrl+x

but it does not work.

I have line such as

```
this is a sentence
```

i would like to make it

```
this
is
a
sentence
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I always use Ctrl + H (Replace), enable the Regular Expression match (Alt + R) and then execute a replace all on " " to "\n".

Comment: Replacing with "\n" just inserts the "\n" characters. Am I missing something?

Comment: @litturt You need to enable the Regular Expressions match (Alt + R or the top-left `.*` button).

Comment: Cool, that worked flawlessly. I used it to separate a comma delimited list into lines for pasting into excel. Search and replace ", " with \n.

Answer (score 19):

for Mac, select the first space between "this" and "is" then press command+d to select the same pattern in the file, then press enter~

Comment: Also good and easy solution for Windows using ctrl+d instead of command+d.

Comment: for Mac, ⌃ + ⌘ + G    Select all occurrences of current selection 
,then enter

Answer (score 8):

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/split-into-lines/10196/5

Hilight your space, press Alt+F3 (windows) to select all, hit return.